# Mapping FBA Roles to SharePoint Groups in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I've already set up Membership and Role Providers in SP2013 and a custom login page for FBA.  I can login as one of my FBA-based users, so I know the connection to the database works.  However, I'm really struggling trying to incorporate my FBA-based roles into SharePoint.  How do I map "FBARole1", for example, to the SharePoint "Owners" group for my site, such that anyone I put into "FBARole1" will automatically be an owner of the site?

I go into Site Settings-->Site Permissions.  I click on "Grant Permissions".  It asks me to enter names, email addresses, or "Everyone".  Makes no mention of roles.  I enter any of my role names and it won't resolve it.  It can find my FBA users, just not my FBA roles.  I can't think of any other place in SP to do this.

I've verified that my role provider "plumbing" works.  I have a web part that checks roles for the logged in user, and it's finding them just fine.  So, best I can tell, I'm just missing where in the UI this association gets made.

Again, this is 2013.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I've been struggling with FBA roles and users since 2 days. please can you check if you faced this problem before?  i Have permission problems when assigning permission to FBA role.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604542/fba-user-in-fba-role-is-not-taking-permission-from-sharepoint-group

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure I get it, and this doesn't give me the "warm fuzzies", but here's what I know...

I went back to that dialog box to enter usernames, email addresses, or 'Everyone'.  I found a link that recommended entering the "complete" info for my role provider instead of just the name, so I tried it.  I entered it in the format of {Role provider name}:{role name}.  Lo and behold, it finally resolved.

A few things are weird about this.
1.  From that point on, I have been able to enter the {role name}, skipping the name of the role provider and the colon, and it resolves.  It didn't beforehand.
2.  If I enter the entire {role name}, it now finds it in search.  Before, it didn't.  And, if I hit the backspace key so it's not the ENTIRE {role name}, the search won't find it.  So, if my full role name was "FBARole1", it'll resolve.  If I enter "FBARole", it'll say there are no matches.

Weird, but that's SharePoint 2013, I guess!