# FBA User in FBA role is not taking permission from SharePoint Group

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2013, fba

I've configured FBA with Sharepoint 2013 on my development machine (one server).
I'm able to create FBA Roles and FBA users and i can connect using FBA users.

The problem is when it comes to permission.

I'm adding the FBA Roles to SharePoint Group but the permission is not being granted to the User inside the FBA Role.

I've reviewed the configuration several time, and checked the below:

- web.config of the web application
- web.config of central admin and STS
- Checked the security on the FBA database and giving the application pool account the necessary security on the database.
- The web application configuration (enabling FBA..)

What i'm missing? Why users are not taking the Roles permission?

Comment: Look at this guy's answer to his own question here:
[Roles to Groups][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338515/mapping-fba-roles-to-sharepoint-groups-in-sharepoint-2013?rq=1

Comment: I dont have the problem posted in the post. Sharepoint is able to find my FBA roles but not able to grant permission to the users in the FBA roles after adding the FBA role to a sharepoint group

Comment: I had some similar issue: can you check if your FBA role is visible in the all groups view of the site collection? If, no you probably have added the FBA role to a SharePoint group by code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. This was because the Users and Groups were'nt in the same OU. I was able to resolve this by adding userContainer="xxxxxx" in the role Provider

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9592df6b-d789-49c0-b1ec-142828cdadc8/fba-ldap-domain-group-members-getting-access-denied?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Comment: Hi @Tim Weiss. Welcome to Stack Overflow. i would like to point out to you that you should reserve answers to answer the question. if you would like to get clarifications or ask questions to the OP, the original poster, you should use the comments feature.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Weiss for your reply. In my web.config i'm not using the LDAP MemeberShipProvider, I'm using SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider and SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider. What I'm missing?